# Converting LDAvis output to tiff

Tags: json, tiff, topic-modeling

I'm working on topic modeling and I've recently discovered the excellent library 'LDAvis'. Unfortunately, the visual output of the library is in json, and I do not know how to convert it to tiff. This is the format required for graphs by most academic journals.
What I need is a way to convert the output of LDAvis to tiff.

Here an example I've derived from the 'text2vec' package, from here: https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/issues/235

```
library(text2vec)

library(magrittr)

data("movie_review")

tokens = movie_review$review[1:4000] %>% 
   tolower %>% 
   word_tokenizer
 it = itoken(tokens, ids = movie_review$id[1:4000], progressbar = FALSE)

v = create_vocabulary(it) %>% 
 prune_vocabulary(term_count_min = 10, doc_proportion_max = 0.2)
 vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(v)
 dtm = create_dtm(it, vectorizer, type = "dgTMatrix")


 lda_model = LDA$new(n_topics = 10, doc_topic_prior = 0.1, topic_word_prior = 0.01)

 doc_topic_distr = 
   lda_model$fit_transform(x = dtm, n_iter = 1000, 
                      convergence_tol = 0.001, n_check_convergence = 25, 
                      progressbar = FALSE)

 # this plots LDAvis in current session

 lda_model$plot()
```

What I want to accomplish are graphs like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this is the best I can do, by using of some kind of converter (press "print" the page, and it opens automatically, as a .pdf converter)
[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope...  The picture of the example are in .png. However, anything that can be converted in .png can be converted in .tiff. I can only save the page, then convert the save page in .tiff, but the resolution is very poor